# Magento 2 import products with images

Tags: magento2, product, import, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file with new products that contain local images but I am receiving the following error:

```
Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s):
General system exception happened
URL-key for specific store already exists.
```

I've read a lot but nothing seems to work. Note that every time I did a failed import I truncated the product tables in database. This is what I've tried/already did:

1. The images are in the **pub/media/import** folder as the documentation tells us to
2. I've changed the chmod of these images to 777 just in case
3. The csv file is **UTF-8**
4. The image **doesn't contain the path** in the CSV, just the file name (e.g. 12356.jpg)
5. Checked my categories to make sure they match the existing categories in my store
6. Tried adding other image fields as well instead of just 'base_image' as I did at first to make sure I wasn't missing required fields
7. Turned the CSV file into one line to check if this would work (which it didn't)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was... My customer sent me all these images with names like `4006501283382.01.jpg`. When I tried to move this image to a different folder I realized that this image didn't exist. This is why Magento stopped importing.

Really bad that Magento doesn't show an error like "Image not found".

Answer (score 2):

You have to put image in directory `magnetoroot/pub/media/import/` e.g. `magnetoroot/pub/media/import/12356.jpg`

And in your csv field **base_image** have to value **/12356.jpg** (with slash).

Comment: I already have the images in that folder. Adding a slash to the values under base_images does not make a difference

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be occur due to various errors. In my case, I made all my image files name to lowercase and used only letters and numbers in file name. Then import worked perfectly. Note: Make sure all your files have 777 permission.

Now if you need to rename all your files to lowercase using command line (cmd), move (cd) to image directory and use following code

```
ls | while read upName; do loName=`echo "${upName}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`; mv "$upName" "$loName"; done
```

Hope this will help